# Rainbow-me React Native chart not showing Path

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I am using `@rainbow-me/animated-charts` to make simple charts but the line path seems to be missing.

I copied the code below from their NPM github but it only shows a black box (i'm assuming its just the background of the chart) but the main line path is missing. Any help?

```
export const data = [
  {x: 1453075200, y: 1.47},
  {x: 1453161600, y: 1.37},
  {x: 1453248000, y: 1.53},
  {x: 1453334400, y: 1.54},
  {x: 1453420800, y: 1.52},
  {x: 1453507200, y: 2.03},
  {x: 1453593600, y: 2.1},
  {x: 1453680000, y: 2.5},
  {x: 1453766400, y: 2.3},
  {x: 1453852800, y: 2.42},
  {x: 1453939200, y: 2.55},
  {x: 1454025600, y: 2.41},
  {x: 1454112000, y: 2.43},
  {x: 1454198400, y: 2.2},
];
const {width: SIZE} = Dimensions.get('window');
const points = monotoneCubicInterpolation(data)(40);

const App = () => (
  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
    <ChartPathProvider data={{points: points, smoothingStrategy: 'bezier'}}>
      <ChartPath height={SIZE / 2} stroke="yellow" width={SIZE} />
      <ChartDot style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
    </ChartPathProvider>
  </View>
);
```

This is all that I am seeing on the iphone simulator.

[image: iphone simulator]

Answer (score 1):

Change:

> const points = monotoneCubicInterpolation(data)(40);

To:

> const points = monotoneCubicInterpolation({ data, range: 40 })